# <select> ::before icon not clickable

Tags: html, css

I have a select element with a few options, but the icon that is rendered is not part of the element and therefore not clickable. Any ideas?

[image]

***My code***

**html**

```
<div class="styled-select icon-drop-down">
  <select class="select">
    <option value="low">Sort by: Low</option>
    <option value="high">Sort by: High</option>
    <option value="long text">long text</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

**css**

```
.styled-select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
   width: 100%;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline;
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 0;
   border: none;

   &.icon-drop-down::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    color: $dark-grey;
        transform: scale(0.7);
   }
}
```

Comment: Look into css pointer-event.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` on the pseudo element will enable you to "click through" the pseudo element as if it was not there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @wf4, doesn't that qualify as an answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`pointer-events: none;` on the pseudo element will enable you to "click through" the pseudo element as if it was not there.

For more information see:
http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar issue, add `pointer-events: none;` to sudo class style, only fix the issue in chrome and firefox, but it doesn't work properly in IE11. I used `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` together with `pointer-events: none;` fix the issue in IE browser.